# SQL error in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
conn.Open();
String sql = "select CATEGORIES.CAT_NAME,PRODUCTS.PRO_MODEL,PRODUCTS.PRO_NAME,PRODUCTS.PRO_PRICE,PRODUCTS.PRO_IMAGE,PRODUCTS.PRO_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTS.PRO_STATUS,PRODUCTS.PRO_ACTIVE" +
"from PRODUCTS INNER JOIN CATEGORIES on PRODUCTS.CAT_ID = CATEGORIES.CAT_ID";
```

My Query SQL runs fine in MYSQL Server but it has error in C# code Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'. hope have answer soon

Answer (score 5):

You need to **add space** between (`.PRO_ACTIVE"` and `"from`)  string concatenation.

```
.PRO_ACTIVE " + "from...
```

So your query should be:

```
String sql = "select CATEGORIES.CAT_NAME,PRODUCTS.PRO_MODEL,PRODUCTS.PRO_NAME,PRODUCTS.PRO_PRICE,PRODUCTS.PRO_IMAGE,PRODUCTS.PRO_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTS.PRO_STATUS,PRODUCTS.PRO_ACTIVE" 
+ " " +//explicit space 
"from PRODUCTS INNER JOIN CATEGORIES on PRODUCTS.CAT_ID = CATEGORIES.CAT_ID";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a space at the end of the first line of your string -- C# doesn't put line feeds in.

Answer (score 2):

change it to:

```
String sql = "select CATEGORIES.CAT_NAME,PRODUCTS.PRO_MODEL,PRODUCTS.PRO_NAME,PRODUCTS.PRO_PRICE,PRODUCTS.PRO_IMAGE,PRODUCTS.PRO_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTS.PRO_STATUS,PRODUCTS.PRO_ACTIVE" +
    " from PRODUCTS INNER JOIN CATEGORIES on PRODUCTS.CAT_ID = CATEGORIES.CAT_ID";
```

A space was missing between "..PRODUCTS.PRO_ACTIVE" and "from PRODUCTS.."